# Map Activity starting as Main Activity

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

I'm creating a simple app that consists in three (3) activities:

- MainActivity -> For registering new users
- LoginActivity -> For Sign in already registered users
- HomeActivity -> Which for the moment shows a Google Map

I'd like to start the app with the MainActivity so in my Android Manifest I've defined that way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MapActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_map"/>
<activity android:name=".VerifyPhoneActivity" />
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However,  the problem is when I start the app automatically sends me to the HomeActivity (the Google Map Activity).

How could I solve this?

My HomeActivity.java:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your main activity code

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually editing your launching configurations. Go to run --> edit configurations and then go under launch options --> launch and choose specified activity. There, select `MainActivity`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just tried it, however didn't work. By the way, I created Google Maps Activity, don't know why but when I lauch my app it only shows me the MapsActivity  inspite I have declared my Main Activity as the launch at start one

Comment: Hmm..interesting. Maybe try cold booting your emulator by navigating to the AVD manager(icon on top right with a phone/ android symbol). Then click the down arrow on your device and try cold boot now. Once you restart it, try again. Also, if you have any errors in any of your activities, that could be the reason as well.